# How can I stop setInterval on another button click?

Tags: javascript

I have created a setInterval function that scrolls onlimited times and two buttons start and end, I want when I click on start button the condition starts and when clicked on end the condition stops. Is there any way to do that? Here is my code:

pophtml:-

```
 <button class="input-btn start-button"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i> Start</button>
    <button class="input-btn scrap-button"><i class="fa fa-share-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Export to csv</button>
     <button class="input-btn end-button"><i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true"></i> End</button>
```

popup js:-

```
   document.querySelector(".end-button").addEventListener("click", function () {
   chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "end"});
    });
});
```

my content.js:-

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    var interval = '';
   if(request.action == 'start'){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
              },1000);
        }

       else if(request.action == 'scrap')
       {
        alert('work in process');

       }
       else if(request.action == 'end')
       {
        clearInterval(interval);

       }
       else
       {
        alert('Wrong button placed')
       }
});
```

i tried it by using that previous method present but i am not getting which id to pass...

Comment: i saw that tried doing with that but that is not working in mine

Comment: Please share that code that you've tried

Comment: `setInterval` will return an id, to stop it use the id on `clearInterval(id);`

Comment: @rahulshukla Create the variable before the `if`, otherwise the variable won't exist in the `else if`. `var interval; if (request.action == 'start') { interval = setInterval(...`

Comment: i tried by giving it the id too but the function inside my loop after start is for scroller that hits after every 10 seconds and i want it to stop when i click on end button i am adding the complete code please check

Answer (score 0):

Use `clearInterval(intervalID)` to clear interval.

```js
var interval = '';
if (request.action == 'start') {
   interval = setInterval(function() {
        $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
   },1000);
}
 else if (request.action == 'end'){
   // code to stop previous process
   clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: its not working for mee when i clicked on end button its the process is not stopped

Comment: @rahulshukla can you provide the full code ?

Comment: i provided the full code above its a chorme extension code basically and i tried by declaring that variable but that is not working for mee.i am trying to check the id that is comming in interval but its changing continously.